# Loss function for Hierarchical Multi-label classification

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification, nlp

I am looking to try different loss functions for a hierarchical multi-label classification problem. So far, I have been training different models or submodels (e.g., a simple MLP branch inside a bigger model) that either deal with different levels of classification, yielding a binary vector. I have been using BCE and summing all the losses existing in the model before backpropagating.

I am considering trying other losses like MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss and MultiLabelMarginLoss. What other loss functions are worth to try? hamming loss perhaps or a variation?
Is it better to sum all the losses and backpropagate or do multiple backpropagations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I am about to do hierachical multi-label classification. What loss function did you use finally?